# My figures don't align

Tags: floats, subcaption

I have three subfigures within a figure, and for some reason the one on the left (including it's caption) lines up lower than the other two. I'm sure it must be some typo, but I just don't see it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{images/DW-MD-T1}
        \caption{V-shape in high density
        \label{fig:DW-MD-T1}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{images/DW-MD-T1}
        \caption{Line-shape in medium density
        \label{fig:DW-MD-T2}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{images/DW-MD-T3}
        \caption{Line-shape in medium density
        \label{fig:DW-MD-T3}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A V-shaped DO-formation meets a medium density crowd; (a) The crowd starts to move aside. The closer agents start adjusting their velocity to flee from the formation. (b) The agents directly in front of the formation don't get a chance to move aside as they are only steered ahead; (c) The agents that did not get a chance to flee get overrun.}
    \label{fig:DW-MD-T}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Try replacing all the `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`.

Comment: Isn't your subfigures too large ? If it work like minipages of those kind of environment, they could have an undeclared border of nonzero width... do they align with width=0.25\textwidth (or anything small enough) ?

Answer (score 1):

I used package `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%% Delete [demo]
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\subfloat[V-shape in high density\label{fig:DW-MD-T1}]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{images/DW-MD-T1}}\hfill
\subfloat[V-shape in high density\label{fig:DW-MD-T2}]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{images/DW-MD-T2}}\hfill
\subfloat[V-shape in high density\label{fig:DW-MD-T3}]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.32\linewidth]{images/DW-MD-T3}}

\caption{A V-shaped DO-formation meets a medium density crowd; (a) The crowd starts to move aside. The closer agents start adjusting their velocity to flee from the formation. (b) The agents directly in front of the formation don't get a chance to move aside as they are only steered ahead; (c) The agents that did not get a chance to flee get overrun.}
    \label{fig:DW-MD-T}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! The captions at the pictures (to be specific the two higher pictures) were to long, somehow causing the picture on the left to drop. Shortenning the caption aligned the pictures.

Comment: I am not sure what you two are saying, @Christian and cgnieder. The complete answer is that the captions are longer than the picture, causing strange alignment. The solution completely solved the problem, there is no longer a question.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your write-up, the three graphs have different heights (though, by design, the same widths). If you want to stick with the machinery provided by the `subcaption` package, I suggest you use the `[t]` placement specifier to inform LaTeX that all three `subfigure` environments (and the material they enclose) should be top-aligned.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth} % note the "[t]" placement directive 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/DW-MD-T1}
        \caption{V-shape in high density
        \label{fig:DW-MD-T1}}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth} % note the "[t]" placement directive
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/DW-MD-T1}
        \caption{Line-shape in medium density
        \label{fig:DW-MD-T2}}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}% note the "[t]" placement directive
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/DW-MD-T3}
        \caption{Line-shape in medium density
        \label{fig:DW-MD-T3}}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip 
    % Suggestion: move the subfigure legends out of the main caption
    (a)~The crowd starts to move aside. The closer agents start adjusting their  
    velocity to flee from the formation. (b)~The agents directly in front of the  
    formation don't get a chance to move aside as they are only steered ahead. 
    (c)~The agents who did not get a chance to flee get overrun.

    \caption{A V-shaped DO-formation meets a medium density crowd}
    \label{fig:DW-MD-T}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```